# MongoDb With Php Dll Not Working

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having wamp on my windows machine with php 5.5.12 and I have installed mongodb 3.2.0 (64 bit) and added php 1.5.7 dll in wampp extension and completed all the necessary things which required to connect with the mongodb.

Here is my code for connecting the mongoDb.

```
<?php
           // connect to mongodb
           $m = new MongoClient();

           echo "Connection to database successfully";
           // select a database
           $db = $m->portal;

           echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

[error message while connecting to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfaRR.png)

Comment: Obviously, you didn't, otherwise there would not be an error while using it. So show us the relevant parts of your php.ini [by editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34332869/edit)

Answer (score 0):

6.8 Mongo and instantiating the class as follows

[php info mongo db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50IUg.jpg)

```
/*Hello I'm Using 1.6.8 Mongo and instantiating the class as follows*/

$mongo = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongo->gwb;
$collection = $db->users;
```